Create GCP IAM principals with roles by loop
I want to create multiple iam users with multiple roles but can't manage to do it so far any ideas how to do?
.tfvars
iam_members = {
  "user_testuser@example.com" = {
    member = "user:testuser@example.com"
    roles  = [
      "roles/cloudasset.owner",
      "roles/datastore.backupsAdmin"
    ]
  },
  "user_john@example.com" = {
    member = "user:john@example.com"
    roles  = [
      "roles/viewer",
      "roles/logging.viewer"
    ]
  }
}

variables.tf
variable "iam_members" {
  type = map(object({
    member = string
    roles  = set(string)
  }))
}

main.tf
resource "google_project_iam_member" "member_roles" {
  for_each = {
    for member_key, member_info in var.iam_members : 
    for role in member_info.roles : "${member_info.member}-${role}" => {
      member = member_info.member
      role   = role
    }
  }

  project = "your-project-id"
  role    = each.value.role
  member  = each.value.member
}

i got these two errors for second for
Invalid 'for' expression: Key expression is required when building an object
Invalid 'for' expression: Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression


Did you have time to check my above Solution? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.
